# login button style properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using this login control:

```
<asp:Login runat="server"  
id="BlogLogin"  UserNameLabelText="Username"  TitleText="" 
MembershipProvider="EktronMembershipProvider" LoginButtonText="Login" RememberMeText="Remember Me" Font-Bold="true"
DisplayRememeberMe="False">   
</asp:Login>
```

and i am trying to set the `loginbuttonstyle` properties to align to left, since this is aligned to right, by default.  I dont see much option here to set the alignment to left.
How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the `LoginButtonStyle-CssClass` attribute and in your css give the class you specified a `float:left` style

```
<asp:Login id="BlogLogin" runat="server"  
    UserNameLabelText="Username" 
    TitleText="" 
    MembershipProvider="EktronMembershipProvider"  
    LoginButtonText="Login"  
    RememberMeText="Remember Me"  
    Font-Bold="true"
    DisplayRememeberMe="False"
    LoginButtonStyle-CssClass="login-button"><!-- <<< add this attribute -->
</asp:Login>
```

then in your css:

```
.login-button {float:left;}
```

Comment: Any idea how to center the login button instead? :)